# R sample a row of a dataframe based on a percentile value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` with 500 rows. I would like to sample the row of `df` based on a given percentile value.

For example, if the percentile value is 0.73 I would like to sample the `0.73 * 500 = 365th` row. If it is 0.7212 I would like to sample the `0.7212*500 = 360.6 = 370th` row (here it has been rounded to the nearest integer value).

As an extension of this I would like to perform the same with a vector of percentile values. For example if the vector is `c(0.73,0.7212)` then I would like to return a dataframe that consists of rows 365 and 370 of the original dataframe `df`.

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: It's `0.7212*500 = 360.6 = 361th` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
percentile_index <- function(data, p){
  rows <- ceiling(p * nrow(data))
  data[rows, ]
}
```

Example:

```r
dat <- data.frame(col1 = 1:500, col2 = rnorm(500))
percentile_index(dat, c(0.73,0.7212))
#    col1      col2
#365  365 0.1910813
#361  361 0.3870956
```

or simply:

```r
dat[ceiling(c(0.73,0.7212) * nrow(dat)), ]
```